# My Keras convolutional model predicted the same image which were imported from different paths, but the prediction results are different

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I created a CNN model for predicting fashions using the *mnist fashion dataset*. After the model has been trained, I tried predicting one of the test images that are loaded from Keras and another image that is identical but imported from my PC onto my Google Colab notebook, and it turns out, the prediction results are not the same. How can I solve this problem?

This is how I imported the dataset:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
```

Data manipulation:

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical
yTest = to_categorical(y_test)
yTrain = to_categorical(y_train)
xTrain = x_train.reshape((60000, 28, 28, 1))
xTest = x_test.reshape(10000, 28, 28, 1)
```

Model Setup:

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, Dropout, MaxPool2D, BatchNormalization
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

model = keras.Sequential()

#Adding the convolutional layer
model.add(Conv2D(50, kernel_size=3, activation='relu',padding = 'same', input_shape = (28, 28, 1)))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = 1, padding = 'valid'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv2D(40, kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = 1, padding = 'valid'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv2D(30, kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = 2, padding = 'valid'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv2D(10, kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

#Connecting the CNN layers to the ANN
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(60, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(40, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(40, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'softmax'))
model.load_weights('mnist_fashion.h5')

# Compiling the model
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy']
```

The model for training:

```
model = keras.Sequential()

#Adding the convolutional layer
model.add(Conv2D(50, kernel_size=3, activation='relu',padding = 'same', input_shape = (28, 28, 1)))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = 1, padding = 'valid'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv2D(40, kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = 1, padding = 'valid'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv2D(30, kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = 2, padding = 'valid'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv2D(10, kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

#Connecting the CNN layers to the ANN
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(60, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(40, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(40, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'softmax'))
```

The model's Performance:

```
            precision    recall  f1-score   support

       0       0.89      0.88      0.88      1000
       1       0.99      0.99      0.99      1000
       2       0.88      0.89      0.89      1000
       3       0.93      0.93      0.93      1000
       4       0.87      0.89      0.88      1000
       5       0.99      0.98      0.99      1000
       6       0.79      0.78      0.78      1000
       7       0.97      0.98      0.97      1000
       8       0.99      0.98      0.99      1000
       9       0.97      0.97      0.97      1000



   accuracy                           0.93     10000
   macro avg       0.93      0.93      0.93     10000
   weighted avg    0.93      0.93      0.93     10000
```

**Picture from dataset prediction**

```
 #From the dataset
    import numpy as np
    image = xTrain[0].reshape(1, 28, 28, 1)
    prd = model.predict(image)
    new_prd = np.argmax(prd, axis  = 1)
    print(f"Prediction = {new_prd}")
    print(f"Full Prediction = {prd}")
    print(f"Label = {y_train[0]}")
```

**Dataset Result**

```
Prediction = [9]
Full Prediction = [[1.6268513e-07 2.3548612e-08 1.5456487e-07 8.6898848e-07 1.9692785e-09
  4.4544859e-04 6.6932116e-06 1.4004705e-02 4.1784686e-05 9.8550016e-01]]
Label = 9
```

**Imported picture prediction**

```
imported_img = plt.imread("mnist fashion sample.png")
yolo = imported_img.reshape(1, 28, 28, 1)
super_prd = model.predict(yolo)
prediction = np.argmax(super_prd, axis = 1)
print(f"Prediction = {prediction}")
print(f"Full Prediction = {super_prd}")
print(f"Label = {y_train[0]}")
```

**Imported picture prediction result**

```
Prediction = [8]
Full Prediction = [[2.49403762e-04 1.69450897e-04 4.47237398e-04 3.05729372e-05
  1.10463676e-04 4.34053177e-03 5.16198808e-04 8.16224664e-02
  8.73587310e-01 3.89263593e-02]]
Label = 9
```

Comment: plot both the images and show here, also show the image array values

Comment: Oops. According to its documentation, it doesn't support random seed. Sorry for the incorrect answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem!

What I did wrong was that I did not normalize the pictures before training. This may cause an error because the data pixel range can be too complex for the relu activation function to calculate or predict.

Thank you!!!